# How do i concatinate some element of array and recreate array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string. I need to split it and assign values to hash. But before assigning it, I need to modify the original array and concatenate some of its elements then recreate the array again. Please help me on how to do it in ruby.

Consider

```
  array = ["unix", "2", "[", "ACC", "]", "STREAM", "LISTENING", "12459", "tmp/control"].
```

I need to concatenate "[", "ACC", "]".

Now the new Array should look like

```
  array = ["unix", "2", "[ ACC ]", "STREAM", "LISTENING", "12459", "tmp/control"].
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I wonder how people create complexities

Comment: Show the original string, perhaps there is a better way to split it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = ["unix", "2", "[", "ACC", "]", "STREAM", "LISTENING", "12459", "tmp/control"]
m,n = array.index('['),array.index(']')
array[m..n]=array[m..n].join(" ")
p array 
# => ["unix", "2", "[ ACC ]", "STREAM", "LISTENING", "12459", "tmp/control"]
```

Comment: Missing one `,` in case of ` array = ["unix", "2", "[", "ACC", "ACC2", "]", "STREAM", "LISTENING", "12459", "tmp/control"]` :)

Comment: @AmolPujari OP didn't mention that...In such a case this answer needs to be changed... :)

Comment: its would be interested to know and review code generating the input array here.

Comment: It is interesting to see an accepted answer with 4 comments and not a singl upvote. +1

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer as 1: The accepted solution only works with one set of square brackets and 2: How often do you actually get to solve something using flip flop?

```
array = ["unix", "2", "[", "ACC", "]", "STREAM", "[", "some",  "other", "]", "x"]

array = array.chunk{|x| (x=='['..x==']') ? true : false }
            .map{|join, array| join ? array.join(' ') : array}
            .flatten

p array #=> ["unix", "2", "[ ACC ]", "STREAM", "[ some other ]", "x"]
```